# Python Global List keeps getting cleared after appending within recursive function

Tags: python, algorithm

For some reason, the list `solutions` keeps getting cleared and filled with empty lists instead of lists of lengths of 9. Not sure why, the variable isn't used anywhere else

```
def check_valid(board, n):
    for i in range(len(board)):
        if i >= n*(n-1):
            return True
        try:
            #If not Right End
            if (i+1)%n != 0:
                if board[i] == board[i+n+1] == 1: #If same as bottom right 1
                    return False
                if -1*board[i] == board[i+1]: #If opposite of adjacent right
                    return False
            #If not Left End
            if i%n != 0:
                if board[i] == board[i+n-1] == -1: #If same as bottom left -1
                    return False
        except IndexError:
            continue
    return True

solutions = []

def run_board(board, n):
    if len(board) == n**2:
        print(board)
        solutions.append(board)
        if solutions[-1] == [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1]:
            print('lol')
        return
    for k in [-1, 0, 1]:
        board.append(k)
        if check_valid(board, n):
            run_board(board, n)
        board.pop()
        

run_board(board = [], n = 3)


print(solutions)
```

I don't know if this has something to do with the function running recursively and weird scoping

Comment: `solutions.append(board)` doesn't make a copy of `board`; all subsequent changes to `board` will be visible in the final value of `solutions`.  You want something like `solutions.append(board.copy())` to take a snapshot of the solutions that are found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of plain `append(board)` you can use

```
solutions.append(board.copy())
```

This seems to not output empty lists.

Comment: It does work now, thanks. But I don't understand why. I know that reassigning a list to another list simply points to the same list, but why does this happen with appending? Furthermore, while debugging the code, the `solutions` variable did get appended to while running.